# Running face_recognition model lead to "python has stopped working"

Tags: python-3.x, anaconda, face-recognition

I tried running the following code:

```py
     import face_recognition
     known_image = face_recognition.load_image_file("biden.jpg")
     unknown_image = face_recognition.load_image_file("unknown.jpg")

     biden_encoding = face_recognition.face_encodings(known_image)[0]
     unknown_encoding = face_recognition.face_encodings(unknown_image)[0]

     results = face_recognition.compare_faces([biden_encoding], unknown_encoding)
```

the `known_image` and `unknown_image` have the type `numpy.ndarray` and the values get loaded in it. But while calling the function `face_recognition.face_encodings`, the following message appears:

```
 Python has stopped working. Kernel has been dead and restarted.
```

Can't figure out what's happening?

Answer (score 0):

What are you jupyter, python versions?

**Reason 1:** Broken installation

Can you try uninstalling all of:

```
ipykernel
ipython
jupyter_client
jupyter_core
traitlets
ipython_genutils
```

More information [here.](https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/issues/1892)

**Reason 2**: Data are huge, memory is not enough, kernel dies

Comment: python: 3.6.9 jupyter: 6.0.1

Comment: the jupyter is opening and working fine. It is only when I call face_recognition.face_encodings the issue arises

Comment: install the latest version of `face_recognition` again please

Comment: see also here: https://github.com/ageitgey/face_recognition/issues/813

Comment: can you upload the images? I want to reproduce this problem.

Comment: I have added the screenshot